# Email Plaintext

Tags: email, virus

I'm interested in viewing emails without "opening" them up.  In other words, I'd like to view the the "plaintext", or text that an email is composed of - being able to see the html or whatever else lies in the plaintext.  The whole point is to not use any html, javascript, or whatever else would be "activated" by the computer once the email is opened - in effect, veiwing the entire email in text without the process of starting a virus.

Is this possible?  Which programs or applications can do this?  How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google shows that you can do this in [Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/read-email-messages-in-plain-text-16dfe54a-fadc-4261-b2ce-19ad072ed7e3)

```
Click the File tab.

Click Options.

Click Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings.

Click Email Security.

Under Read as Plain Text, select the Read all standard mail in plain text check box.
```

I am confident that this is an option for other mail clients as well.